# how to i configure spring webflux project in aws api gateway for stream of Flux object

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, spring-webflux, project-reactor

let say I have spring webflux exposed as a rest endpoint and it publish flux object as a content-type of text/event-stream.
1.

```
@RestController
public class ABC{

@GetMapping(value = "/event", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> event(String clientId) {
        Flux<Long> interval = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).take(10).onBackpressureBuffer(10);
        Flux<String> stream = Flux.fromStream(java.util.stream.Stream.generate(() -> "my data as event "));

        return Flux.zip(interval, stream).map(Tuple2<Long, String>::getT2);
    }
}
```

2. this is working absolutely fine when i hit url on localhost using chrome or curl.
3. 

I want to configure this in AWS as api gateway http or a Rest EndPoint but the problem is that this MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE is not giving me data back when i hit api gateway url using curl or any other tool.

Please let me know how do I configure spring webflux reative project on api gateway so that i can get back stream of data.

Comment: Any Solution for this?

Comment: Yes, basically AWS api gateway has default timeout of 30 seconds. so alternatively we are using AWS ALB tool, it has no timeout. so that is what we are using.